# Map/reduce in RavenDB throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, nosql, mapreduce, ravendb

I am having difficulties getting a map / reduce operation to work. I'm a hobbyist with C#, so probably it is partly due to my lack of experience with lambda's and linq to thoroughly analyse and understand the cause (what is an object create expression) leading to the error.

The code compiles perfectly, but when executed it throws an exception and I don't understand what part is not correct.

When I disable the reduce operation the error remains, so I assume it has to do with
the Map part.

RavenDB version is: RavenDB-Build-573

This is the exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Variable
initializer select must have a lambda expression with an object create
expression

And I provide RavenDB with the index like this:

```cs
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(FullTree).Assembly, store);
```

The Entity object is a simple class, featuring an int Id, and an int ParentId.

This is the map / reduce part:

```cs
public class FullTreeObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}

public class FullTree : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Entity,FullTreeObject>
   {
       public FullTree()
       {

           Map = entities => from entity in entities
                             let ids = new object[]
                               {
                                   new { entity.Id, Count = 0,
entity.ParentId },
                                   new { Id = entity.ParentId, Count
= 1, ParentId = (string)null}
                               }
                             from id in ids
                             select id;

           Reduce = results => from result in results
                               group result by result.Id into g
                               let parent = g.FirstOrDefault(x =>
x.ParentId != null)
                               select new
                               {
                                   Id = g.Key,
                                   Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count),
                                   ParentId = parent ==
(object)null ? (object)null : parent.ParentId
                               };

       }
   }
```

Hope someone can provide me with some clues. Thanks in advance.

--

In reaction to the input I've modified the map/reduce implementation. RavenDB requires map and reduce output the same type but to be honest, this can't be right since I'm outputing values of the entity object, and not those aquired in the array. But I cannot reach those values with intellisense.

The index is created in the RavenDB studio, but no results are returned so I can assume my implementation is faulty.

```
public class FullTree : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Entity,FullTreeObject>
    {
        public FullTree()
        {
            Map = entities => from entity in entities
                              let ids = new object[]
                                { 
                                    new { entity.Id, Count = 0, entity.ParentId }, 
                                    new { Id = entity.ParentId, Count = 1, ParentId = (string)null} 
                                } 
                              from id in ids
                              select new { 
                                    entity.Id,
                                    Count = 1,
                                    entity.ParentId
                              };


            Reduce = results => from result in results
                                group result by result.Id into g
                                let parent = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ParentId != null)
                                select new
                                {
                                    Id = g.Key,
                                    Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count), 
                                    ParentId = parent == (object)null ? (object)null : parent.ParentId
                                };
        }
    }
```

Update on Build 601:

```
public class FullTree : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Entity, FullTree.ReduceResult>
{

    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
    } 
    public FullTree()
    {
        Map = entities => from entity in entities
                          let items = new[]
                            { 
                                new { Id = (int) entity.Id, Count = (int) 0, ParentId = (int) entity.ParentId }, 
                                new { Id = (int) entity.ParentId, Count = (int) 1, ParentId = (int) 0} 
                            } 
                          from item in items
                          select new { 
                                Id = item.Id,
                                Count = item.Count,
                                ParentId = item.ParentId
                          };


        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Id into g
                            let itemWithParent = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ParentId != 0)
                            select new
                            {
                                Id = g.Key,
                                Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count),
                                ParentId = (itemWithParent == null) ? (int)0 : itemWithParent.ParentId
                            };
    }
}
```

Error returned:
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6111651
   Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadStringInternal(Func`1 getResponse) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:231

[InvalidOperationException: {
  "Url": "/indexes/FullTree",
  "Error": "System.InvalidOperationException: Could not understand query: \r\n-- line 2 col 55: invalid NewExpression\r\n-- line 2 col 91: Can't parse double .0.0\r\n-- line 2 col 183: Can't parse double .0.0\r\n-- line 2 col 275: Can't parse double .0.0\r\n\r\n   at Raven.Database.Linq.QueryParsingUtils.GetVariableDeclarationForLinqMethods(String query, Boolean requiresSelectNewAnonymousType) in c:\Builds\raven-unstable\Raven.Database\Linq\QueryParsingUtils.cs:line 122\r\n   at Raven.Database.Linq.DynamicViewCompiler.TransformMapDefinitionFromLinqMethodSyntax(String query, String& entityName) in c:\Builds\raven-unstable\Raven.Database\Linq\DynamicViewCompiler.cs:line 355\r\n   at Raven.Database.Linq.DynamicViewCompiler.HandleMapFunction(ConstructorDeclaration ctor, String map) in c:\Builds\raven-unstable\Raven.Database\Linq\DynamicViewCompiler.cs:line 132\r\n   at Raven.Database.Linq.DynamicViewCompiler.TransformQueryToClass() in c:\Builds\raven-unstable\Raven.Database\Linq\DynamicViewCompiler.cs:line 97\r\n   at Raven.Database.Linq.DynamicViewCompiler.GenerateInstance() in c:\Builds\raven-unstable\Raven.Database\Linq\DynamicViewCompiler.cs:line 489\r\n   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.PutIndex(String name, IndexDefinition definition) in c:\Builds\raven-unstable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 717\r\n   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.Put(IHttpContext context, String index) in c:\Builds\raven-unstable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 72\r\n   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.Respond(IHttpContext context) in c:\Builds\raven-unstable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 49\r\n   at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.DispatchRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\raven-unstable\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 527\r\n   at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.HandleActualRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\raven-unstable\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 303"
}]
   Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadStringInternal(Func`1 getResponse) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:295

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micha, the bug is now fixed. It's within build 601.
To see how you can actually implement an index like the want you asked for, take a look at this test: https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Tests/Bugs/MapRedue/TreeWithChildrenCount.cs

Comment: Nice, gonna try it out today :) 

Do you know what they bugs were?

Comment: Daniel, is it always necessary to cast the values to string types? In my case the Id and ParentId are int. I changed the parentid default value to 0. Again the code compiles but when the index is added RavenDB fails to create the index.

Since your test cleary passes, I must be doing something wrong or not understanding the correct approach.

I appended the code in my opening post. It appears to long for the comment.

Comment: Ids in RavenDB should _always_ be strings. There are a lot of different places where you need them as strings. As for the casting - yes you need the explicit casting so that the expression string builder knows what to do. Even if VS or Resharper suggests to remove them, you need them here.

Comment: I hoped I could just cast them to string :( When I read the articles from Philip (ex: http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/12/ravendb-map-reduce/) about map/reduce he seems to work with int Ids rather then string Ids.

Comment: I thought me code was just wrong, but your test also fails here on 601? It tripples on:

`code`
[InvalidOperationException: {
  "Url": "/indexes/CategoriesWithChildrenCount",
  "Error": "System.InvalidOperationException: Could not understand query: \r\n-- line 2 col 61: invalid NewExpression\r\n-- line 2 col 98: Can't parse double .0.0\r\n-- line 2 col 190: Can't parse double .0.0\r\n-- line 2 col 283: Can't parse double .0.0\r\n\r\n   at Raven.Database.Linq.QueryParsingUtils.GetVariableDeclarationForLinqMethods(String query, Boolean requiresSelectNewAnonymousType) in c....
`code`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply that the Map function must return an anonymous type (it doesn't do that in right now). Further, that anonymous type must have the same properties as the class that you have defined to be the result of the index.

I don't know how to describe it better, but as a rule of thumb one can say that the map function must always end with `select new { YourPropertyName = propValue }`

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the answers so far, really cool. So if I've read this correct, the issue in essence is that the Map function returns nothing, and it should have.

So by changing it from 

'from id in ids select id;'

to (based on saving the results as a FullTreeObject type):

'from id in ids select new {Id = id.id, Count = id.Count, ParentId = id.ParentId};'

So now I've created an anonymous object which become a returnable value which RavenDB should understand.

Did I correctly interpreted this?

Comment: Micha, I've just seen your update. The index should work technically, but it doesn't make any sense because it groups on the Id. What are you trying to do? Maybe open a new question for this, as it's another story.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am trying to implement the map / reduce explained by Ayende: http://ayende.com/blog/4801/leaving-the-relational-mindset-ravendbs-trees

Maybe this clears things up? :)

Comment: Micha, I just tried to get it working and found a bug within raven that makes this fail. I'm sure it will be fixed very soon - I'll let you know.

Comment: Hah! So it is partly due to my gigantic lack of knowledge :D

Comment: There actually two bugs that prevent this two work properly. One of them I have already fixed yesterday, the other is a bit more complex and requires Ayende, I think.

Comment: I'll keep an eye on this thread for new info about this. If there is anything I can do to help, please ask. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a raven instance handy but try replacing  ParentId = (string)null with ParentId = -1 and see if that helps. I have had a few problems with trying to assign nulls in my indexes like that. Clearly this does not solve the problem but might help identify it.

Comment: I'll try this if Daniel's answer doesn't work out, thanks! :)